# Why does Sweet Alert work only in production in this case?

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-hosting, sweetalert

In production I can work with Sweet Alert but when I put the site up, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

I ran `npm install sweetalert` and added these two lines to the Head of index.html:

> < script
>   src="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js">
>
> <   link rel="stylesheet"
>   href="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">

Is that where they should be? Should they be elsewhere / nowhere?

When the page loads, Chrome's console shows these three errors:

> GET https://wfolly.firebaseapp.com/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css 
>   wfolly.firebaseapp.com/:24 
>   GET https://wfolly.firebaseapp.com/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js 
>   wfolly.firebaseapp.com/:25 
>   GET https://wfolly.firebaseapp.com/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css

I've tried deploying the website both with and without the node_modules/sweetalert directory.

I'm a novice. A basic mistake is likely.

Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep

> < link rel="stylesheet"
>   href="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">

at the head to retain changes I made to the CSS but replace the script with

> ```
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
> ```

it works!

Let's perhaps take a moment to thank the people who downvoted the question for their patience and generosity.